# Invalid parameter number in Php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my php code

```
$data=array(
        'title'=>$_POST['title'],
        'description'=>$_POST['description'],
        'image_path'=>$filepath
    );
    print_r($data);
    $result=$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `mir_news`(`title`,`description`,`image_path`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $result->execute($data);
```

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\miradmin\views\add_news.php:24 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\miradmin\views\add_news.php(24):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\miradmin\index.php(46):
>   require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\miradmin\views\add_news.php on line 24

`print_r($data)` will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You only want the `values` of the array, not the `keys`:

```
$result->execute(array_values($data));
```

---

Alternatively, define them differently earlier:

```
$data = array($_POST["title"], $_POST["description"], $filepath);
//...
$result->execute($data);
```

Comment: @BlessanKurien no worries, glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_values` while passing `$data`

$result->execute(array_values($data));
$result->execute($data);

`array_values()` returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

Answer (score -1):

Try to look in the variable "$filepath" where the value comes from?